# Do While Loop doesnt Stop in VBA

Tags: excel, do-while, vba

I have a simple loop but I cant stop it after the condition has been met!

I have a large list of data which the loop is sorting through. The EndRow variable is set to the last row, the CurRow variable to the current row, and it is incremented on each loop. I want it to stop when it gets to the end of the list (ie CurRow=EndRow) but it doesnt stop! Simple mistake im sure, but I cant see it!

```
    Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim CurRow As Integer
Dim EndRow As Integer

EndRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
CurRow = 1
i = 1

Do While CurRow < EndRow

    If Cells(CurRow, 1).Value = "BEGIN:VEVENT" Then
        j = 5
        CurRow = CurRow + 1
        Do Until Cells(CurRow, 1).Value = "BEGIN:VEVENT"

            Cells(i, j) = Cells(CurRow, 1)
            j = j + 1
            CurRow = CurRow + 1
        Loop
        i = i + 1

    Else
        CurRow = CurRow + 1
    End If


Loop
```

Comment: Is the second loop definitely satisfied?

Comment: you beauty! It is all the way through, untill the very end of the list, when it isnt so it stays in that loop. Thanks

Comment: @SJR Came here to ask that.

Comment: If the list is large - change `Integer` to `Long` at least for `CurRow`.

Comment: You should learn to use the debugger. If you hold down the F8 key to step through the code you should be able to literally see the code being stuck in the inner loop (which I gather is the problem)

Comment: It works fine through the 15,000+ rows, but the data doesnt finish with the keyword "BEGIN:VEVENT" so it never leaves the loop the very last time. I debugged for 100's of loops but I wasnt going to keep going for all 15,000!!

Comment: @Giovanni I see -- you could still do something like set a breakpoint after the inner loop and notice that you never hit the breakpoint.

Comment: I understand what your trying to say, but both loops are continuously used throughout the mass of data so wherever it was put, id be breaking 1000's of times throughout the running of the code. I suppose I couldve put a dummy IF function in with a breakpoint in it for when the value got higher...

Comment: Or just set CurRow to be a few numbers less than EndRow and F8 step the last few entries ^^

Comment: +1 for Glitch_Doctor's suggestion, and I'll also add you could put a STOP in, eg: If curRow = 15000 Then Stop - There's always a way

Comment: looks like I need to learn different ways of debugging... :) thanks all